# ostrio:files & Meteor Remove File

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm currently using ostrio:files to manage my image gallery. 
I found no documentation about how to remove/delete images inserted and uploaded programatically.
Here is the official documentation on atmosphere:https://atmospherejs.com/ostrio/files

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have answered your question, but you should have been able to find this information yourself. It's good form to do your best before you ask questions

Answer (score 2):

There is documentation on how to remove files from the collection:

https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/remove

On this page: https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/wiki/AWS-S3-Integration

There is some code to intercept file removal:

```
  // Intercept FilesCollection's remove method to remove file from AWS:S3
  const _origRemove = UserFiles.remove;
  UserFiles.remove = function (search) {
    const cursor = this.collection.find(search);
    cursor.forEach((fileRef) => {
      _.each(fileRef.versions, (vRef) => {
        if (vRef && vRef.meta && vRef.meta.pipePath) {
          // Remove the object from AWS:S3 first, then we will call the original FilesCollection remove
          s3.deleteObject({
            Bucket: s3Conf.bucket,
            Key: vRef.meta.pipePath,
          }, (error) => {
            bound(() => {
              if (error) {
                console.error(error);
              }
            });
          });
        }
      });
    });

    //remove original file from database
    _origRemove.call(this, search);
  };
} else {
  throw new Meteor.Error(401, 'Missing Meteor file settings');
}
```